# Приведите пожалуйста мне метафору и аналогию, что такое global и nonlocal функции

Tags: python-3.x, функции, define

Я новичок в программировании и изучении языка python, и никак не могу усвоить, что такое функции и как их юзать, объясните пожалуйста понятным языком, желательно с приведением метафор и аналогий , заранее всем спасибо

Comment: Так Вам объяснить функции нужно или ключевые слова `global`, `nonlocal`?

Answer (score 0):

Всё в `Python` — это объект. И у каждого объекта есть имя.

Но в одной программе может быть несколько одинаковых имён, причём не конфликтующих. Достигается это благодаря [областям видимости](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

***Пример:***

```py
# Глобальная область видимости
# Коробка на улице
box = 0  

# Мой дом — отдельная область видимости
def my_house():
    # Локальная область видимости функции my_house
    # Нелокальная область видимости функции closet
    # Коробка в прихожей моего дома
    box = 1

    # Шкаф в моём доме — отдельная область видимости
    def closet():
        # Локальная область видимости функции closet
        # Коробка в шкафу в моём доме
        box = 2
```

В программе выше есть три переменные `box`, поэтому инструкция `print(box)` будет выводить разные значения в зависимости от того, где её выполнять.

С помощью ключевых слов `global` и `nonlocal` мы можем обратиться к конкретной переменной: глобальной (`box = 0`) или нелокальной (на область видимости выше, но не в глобальную).

В моём примере обращаться к нелокальной переменной `box = 1` можно только из функции `closet`.

Comment: Аналогия ни как нельзя открыть шкаф и взять из него коробку, при этом не открыв двери дома)